# Minting multiple ERC721 tokens estimating gas cost error

Tags: solidity, nft, gas-price, gas-estimate, mint

I have a function to mint multiple NFTs in my smart contract (max 10). I have another function to transfer the tokens to the `msg.sender`. Using hardhat locally, this all works nicely. However on the Rinkeby network this fails to be able to estimate gas costs and I can't mint tokens. I have ethereum in my wallet and other transactions are going through no problem.

```
    function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable whenMintNotPaused() {
        require(_tokenIdTracker.current() + _mintAmount <= maxAvailableTokens, "all tokens have been minted");
        require(!Address.isContract(msg.sender), "address cannot be a contract");
        require( _mintAmount <= 10, "You can mint a maximum of 10");
        require( msg.value == _salePrice * _mintAmount, "Ether sent is not equal to PRICE * num" );
        payable(treasurer).transfer(msg.value);
        transferNFTs(_mintAmount, msg.sender);
    }

    function transferNFTs(uint256 num, address recipient) private {
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < num; i++){
            uint256 newItemId = initialId + _tokenIdTracker.current(); //keeps a track from 0
            super._safeMint(recipient, newItemId);
            require(_exists(newItemId), "minting the ID failed");
            setRoyalties(newItemId);
            string memory completeURI;
            completeURI = string(abi.encodePacked(Strings.toString(newItemId), suffix));
            _setTokenURI(newItemId, completeURI); 
            _tokenIdTracker.increment();
            emit NftBought(msg.sender, newItemId);
        }
    }
```

If I call the function

```
    console.log("gas price", gasPrice.toString())
    const TX = await contract.connect(accountBuyer).mint(num, {
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther(totalPrice.toString()),
      gasLimit: 21000000,
      gasPrice: gasPrice
    })
```

Then I can get a transaction to occur albeit it doesn't seem to go through (perhaps way to little gas?)

If I don't pass

```
gasLimit: 21000000,
gasPrice: gasPrice
```

Then I get a gas estimation error

```
  reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  error: Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (method="estimateGas",
```

My contract is `ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable,`
and I am using openzeppelin for my libraries

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How much gas does it cost when run locally? 21M is a lot for just 10 tokens. Did you try removing some of the unneeded parts? Like `_setTokenURI` shouldn't be necessary, you can generate on demand by overriding `tokenURI` instead.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Does this happen only on rinkby?